# Using a function to do a %change on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am on python using pandas but running into this issue. I am having a dataset that has the countries on the columns and dates(my months) on the rows. The data consists of the population of an item.

I am required to calculate the % change of population month by month is there a function that I can use to get the data into a dataset with the %change month by month in the format attached?

I am trying to do the apply a function onto the dataset but getting the function to retrieve the previous month's population to do a % change is an issue.

Anyone has any good ideas to get this done? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Show your data as text and your  code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
df.pct_change()
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

First order the data by month (if it isn't already), and then use the `.shift()` function for pandas dataframes

```
df['pct_change'] = (df.US - df.US.shift(1) ) / df.US
```

`.shift()` allows you to shift rows up or down depending on the argument.